# Imprecise SKSpriteNode.zPosition CGFloat values

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cgfloat

I stumbled on what appears to be a bug in SKSpriteNode. When the zPossition is set to a decimal value it later contains an asymptote of the original value. Testing the CGFloat with the same input behaves as expected and the assigned and retrieved values are the same.

Environment: OSX 10.11.6, Xcode 8, Swift 3

Test cases:

```
func test_zPossition_Fails_Equivalence() {

    let sprite:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
    let zPos:CGFloat = 2.1

    sprite.zPosition = zPos

    XCTAssertEqual(sprite.zPosition, zPos)
    // fails: 2.0999... is not equal to 2.1
}


func test_zPossition_Passes_Equivalence() {

    let sprite:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
    let zPos:CGFloat = 2

    sprite.zPosition = zPos

    XCTAssertEqual(sprite.zPosition, zPos)
}

func test_CGFloat_Passes_Equivalence() {

    let zPosA:CGFloat = 2.1
    let zPosB:CGFloat = 2.1

    XCTAssertEqual(zPosA, zPosB)
}
```

Edit: I added another test case to compare the post set values of zPosition

```
func test_zPossition_Passes_Equivalence() {

    let sprite1:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
    let sprite2:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
    let zPos:CGFloat = 2.1

    sprite1.zPosition = zPos
    sprite2.zPosition = sprite1.zPosition

    XCTAssertEqual(sprite1.zPosition, sprite1.zPosition)
    XCTAssertNotEqual(sprite1.zPosition, zPos)
}
```

The value changed but is consistent with itself. Not a bug.

Comment: Not a bug,  some numbers cannot be represented in binary (a power of 2),  there are ways that systems get around this, but sometimes you do not want those optimizations/tricks.  Then there is the issue of casting these numbers across various data types,  losing precision.

Comment: http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/

Comment: My assumption was that a cast was happening somewhere in SKSpriteNode, and I'd added Round to my test cases, but it seemed hacky to me.

Comment: it is definitely doing some kind of casting/converting,  won't know what it is till the source gets released

Comment: my guess is going to double then back to float, losing the representation of 2.1, and instead giving the literal binary value

Comment: I get the difficulties around binary representation of decimals, it's that the value has mutated immediately on assignment, that feels a bit wrong to me. I'd imagine that something is happening inside the zPosition property setter/getter that results in a cast to another type.

Comment: yes, we have no idea what is going on in the background, it is due to the different frameworks like metal and opengl that this is happening (I think opengl uses floats while metal uses doubles) there is nothing you can do about it, but again, it is not a bug, it is the literal z value after you assign it a number.